# my HBase is running ..but whenever i check the status it give the following error

Tags: hadoop, hbase

```
status 'detailed'
14/08/26 00:01:45 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/08/26 00:01:46 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/08/26 00:01:47 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/08/26 00:01:49 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/08/26 00:01:51 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/08/26 00:01:55 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/08/26 00:01:59 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the hbase-site.xml of all your nodes, make sure the `zookeeper.znode.parent` keep consistent!
then use `jps` to check services of all your node, make sure coresponding services start up!